# Flink Kafka Source Operator Reconnect Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to flink, I have a flink pipeline which has 5 Operators, out of which 2 of them are kafka Source Operators consuming kafka messages from 2 different topics. I have checkpointing enabled for every minute on both these sources. I am trying to test a usecase where I bring down kafka and bring back up after 10 mins. 
My flink version is `1.16.1` and same kafka-connector version. The task failure config settings are default not touched, similar with kafka consumer config is default.

To bring down the kafka pods, I scaled them down to 0 and scaled them back to original after 10 mins.

**Expected behaviour**: The operator should reconnect automatically once the kafka is up.

**Actual Behaviour**: The operator is not reconnecting neither task is failing nor the job status is changed. It is stuck in some loop and it only comes back up once I delete both jm and tm pods.

Part of the Logs After the kafka is up and running:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to send request after 30000 ms.
2023-08-29 07:32:01.945 [Source Data Fetcher for Source: Kafka Data source (3/3)#0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  - [Consumer clientId=data-group-2, groupId=data-group] Disconnecting from node 1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 30096 ms.
2023-08-29 07:32:01.945 [Source Data Fetcher for Source: Kafka Data source (3/3)#0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler  - [Consumer clientId=data-group-2, groupId=data-group] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1361712539, epoch=INITIAL) to node 1:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
```

Comment: Did you persist the Kafka data? If you scale pods to zero, then all unmounted data directories will be deleted, so there's no longer anything to consume, and the broker id may change if you'd not otherwise defined it, meaning "node 1" cached connection information may no longer exist, and it cannot reconnect... In practice, you should have at least 3 replica in your topics, and distribute your brokers such that 3 won't fail all at the same time

Comment: I have 2 replicas  and 1 master. My test objective is to bring all brokers down at once and then check if flink job can recover. Do you mean that my test is invalid.
If yes, what happens if the master node goes down.

Comment: Following up on @OneCricketeer question, no we dont persist kafka data, all consumer metadata(group, offset etc) is lost and probably this is the reason why the source reader is not able to connect back. In this case what do you suggest we do? Do note the Job status does not change despite the failure to reconnect. If somehow I can change the job status I can restart the job

Comment: Yes the test is invalid because Kafka won't restart in the same state you shut it down with... You mention pods, so I assume kubernetes? Use Strimzi and review its docs on StatefulSets and PersistentVolumes

Comment: @OneCricketeer even if my test is invalid, In this scenario, Shouldn't my flink job be resilient enough to reconnect without manual intervention. The consumer metadata could be lost because of other reasons also, How should the job behave in that scenario

Comment: It should reconnect... At least, consumers outside of Flink do. The Kafka consumer process caches metadata for 5 minutes, by default, I think, then will request new information, but that also assumes static broker.id's, bootstrap server address is unchanged (pod hostname isn't modified), and a pre-existing topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer It is not reconnecting, pod host names remains unchanged, topics exist. Other spring services works fine after the restart(automatically handled) but only the flink jobs are not reconnecting back until you go and delete tm and jm pods in other words the job is redeployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the issue further, There could be many probable causes to this problem but In my case the issue was kafka client resolved IPs of the kafka brokers at the beginning and caches the information. Since all brokers restart, their IPs are changed but kafka client is still refering to  older IPs, thus getting stuck. 
For more detail you can refer to [KAFKA-7931](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7931)